# printing multiple lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey I wrote a python code (python 2.7.3) with multiple lists, but when I try to print them they always come with a space. I want to print the list in continuous manner but I'm unable to do so. I have one list which have integer values and other with character.

Eg: list1 (integer list has 123) and list2(character list has ABC).

Desired Output: `ABC123`
What I'm getting:  `ABC 123`

What I did:

```
print "".join(list2),int("".join(str(x) for x in list1))
```

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating the two lists you want while printing. Use "+" instead of ",".
Here 'int' will give error as you can concatenate only strings. So try,

```
 print "".join(list2)"".join(str(x) for x in list1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ["A","B","C"]
l2 = [1,2,3]
print "".join(l+map(str,l2))
ABC123
```

`map` casts all `ints` to `str`, it is the same as doing `[str(x) for x in l2]`.

Answer (score 1):

The space comes from the `print` statement. It automatically inserts a space between items separated with comma. I suppose you don't need to covert the concatenated string into an integer, then you concatenate strings from `join` and print them as one.

`print "".join(list2)+"".join(str(x) for x in list1)`

Alternatively you can switch to python3's `print` function, and use its `sep` variable.

```
from __future__ import print_function
letters=['A','B','C']
nums=[1,2,3]
print("".join(letters),int("".join(str(x) for x in nums)), sep="")
```

Comment: Because I left the `int("".join(str(x) for x in list1)`, so it couldn't be concatenated. I removed it now. It should work.

Comment: You are right, did not notice that. Anyways, downvoters should always leave a comment instead of having you guess what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The `,` is what's adding the space since you are printing two things, a string 'ABC' and an integer 123. Try using `+`, which directly adds two strings together so you can print the string 'ABC123'

```
>>> list1=[1,2,3]
>>> list2=['A','B','C']
>>> print "".join(list2),int("".join(str(x) for x in list1))
ABC 123
>>> print "".join(list2)+"".join(str(x) for x in list1)
ABC123
```

Answer (score -1):

`print` adds a single space automatically between commas.

You can use the new print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
print("".join(list2),int("".join(str(x) for x in list1)), sep="")
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

> **Note:** This function is not normally available as a built-in since the
>   name `print` is recognized as the print statement. To disable the
>   statement and use the `print()` function, use this future statement at
>   the top of your module